# Split a vector in R based on sign (+/-)

Tags: r

I would like to split a vector based on its sign. I have a vector that looks like:

```
v <- c(1, 2,-4,-8 ,-9, 4)
```

There are 3 groups in the vector. A positive group (index 1 and 2), a negative group (index 3,4,5) and another positive group (index 6).  I want to get a vector of FIRST index of each group....

So the result I want is vector containing the indicies 1,3,6

I would like this to work if the vector has an arbitrary number of groups of arbitrary size.

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sign` to pick out the signs, and then `diff` to see where this changes.

```
c(1,which(diff(sign(v))!=0)+1)
[1] 1 3 6
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @James's solution is to use `sequence` and `rle`:

```
which(sequence(rle(sign(v))$lengths) == 1)
# [1] 1 3 6
```